# Values in $scope are not visible after location.path

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing problem while building a single page app with angularjs. My app has a login page. If authentication is success, app is routed to home page in which some data is displayed from $scope. However, no data is being displayed after login.

I am using location.path to route to home when sign in successful. For reference, I am trying to print "$scope.homePageDetails" in home.html but nothing is getting printed. Can someone say, what wrong am I doing and how can I resolve this issue?

index.html file:

```
<html>
    <body>
   <nav>
   <ul>
   <li ng-hide="isUserLoggedIn"><a href="#login">       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
  </ul>
  </nav>    

 <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

login.html file:

```
<div>
 <form class="form-signin">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" ng-model="userDetails.userName" required autofocus>
  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" ng-model="userDetails.Password" required>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" ng-click="signIn()">
Sign in</button>
</form>
```

home.html:

```
<p> {{homePageDetails}}</p>
```

angular module and controller:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','$http', '$location'    function($scope,$uibModal,$http, $location, $window) {
$scope.signIn = function(){

    $http({
    url: "http://localhost:3050/postSignIn",
    method: "POST",        
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
       },
    data: $scope.userDetails
    })
    .then(function(response){
            console.log('resp is',response);
            $scope.isUserLoggedIn = true;               
            $location.path('/home');

              $http({
                    url: "http://localhost:3050/getHomePageDetails",
                    method: "GET",        
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                   }        
               })
               .then(function(response){                       
                   $scope.homePageDetails = response.data.slice(0);
               }, function(response){
                // failure callback
                console.log('failure in getting homePageDetails',response);
               });                   
        },        
        function(response){
            // failure callback
            console.log('failure is',response);
        });     
}
}]);
```

module:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
```

router:

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

$routeProvider.when('/home',
{
  templateUrl:    'home.html',
  controller:     'myCtrl'
});

}
```

Comment: What is the controller of login page ? Can you provide full router code

Comment: Your scope for home screen is perhaps different then the one in your signin screen.

Comment: @Thanh:  I have updated the controller. There are no multiple controllers. I am using only one controller. i.e myCtrl.

Comment: Have you posted your code correctly cause I can see some syntax issues here?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$routeProvider
.when('/home',
{
  templateUrl:    'home.html',
  controller:     'myCtrl'
})
.when('/login',
{
 templateUrl:'login.html',
controller:'myCtrl'
})
```